# Sending emails through vba but the modules with functions were not sent

Tags: excel, vba, email

I have some vba code that sends an excel sheet directly through outlook email. I saved the excel file as a .xlsm, so the macros and VBA programs would work on my device. However, when the recipient of the email opens the excel sheet, the modules (which contains certain user defined formulas) are not sent. I was wondering whether there is a way I can ensure that the modules are sent through the email or another place I can place the code for the function so it will be automatically sent through the email.

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have tried looking online for any situations, but all I saw was to put the function in module and there was no explanation about how to send the module with an email created through vba.

Email:

```
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If .HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
End With

'    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
'    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
'        .Cells.Copy
'        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
'        .Cells(1).Select
'    End With
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Part of " & Sourcewb.name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = Range("B61")
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "CS Equipment Pricebook"
        .Body = Range("B30:B40")
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With

'Delete the file you have send
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

Function:

```
Function username()
    username = Environ("Username")
End Function
```

Whenever the email is sent, the module with the function would not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

In order for automatically-running subroutines to work correctly in Microsoft Excel, they must be contained within a Visual Basic module.

You must insert a Visual Basic module into the workbook and then place the code in the new module.

To insert a Visual Basic module:
 - In the Project Explorer in the Visual Basic Editor, activate the workbook that contains the code in question.
 - On the Insert menu, click Module.
 - After the new module is inserted, cut the code from its original location and paste it into the Visual Basic module. Then, save the workbook.

See [VBA code "behind" a worksheet or a workbook may not work in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/213581/vba-code-behind-a-worksheet-or-a-workbook-may-not-work-in-excel) for more information.

Finally, make sure that everything is included to your workbook, see [Where is the Excel Personal Macro Workbook Located?](http://wheatblog.com/2011/08/where-is-the-excel-personal-macro-workbook-located/).

P.S. If you need to distribute your Office-based solution to multiple machines, I'd suggest developing a VSTO based add-in. Read more about them in the [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-excel?view=vs-2019) article.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The modules would work on my computer when I open the file; however, when I send the file as an email attachment with vba code, the module would not be included with the attachment. I looked online and they said a separate add-in would need to be downloaded for each computer that want to access the excel workbook. I was wondering if there is a way to send the modules with the workbook without using an additional add-in